# Don't compare missing / NaN values

Tags: pandas, numpy, comparison, nan, missing-data

How to compare two Series and leave NaN values? For example:

```
s1 = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 3])

s2 = pd.Series([0, 2, 3])

s1.eq(s2).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Desired result:

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: If you keep NaN, the False and True will be turned into float 0/1. Unless you use this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html

Comment: @MarkWang Good point. I'll try to rewrite my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you allow float in the end

```
s1.eq(s2).mask(s1.isna() | s2.isna())
```

or this if you want to keep boolean

```
s1.eq(s2).mask(s1.isna() | s2.isna()).astype("boolean")
```